# SKSpriteNode and SKLightNode not respecting SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When I have a `SKLightNode` in my scene with a `SKSpriteNode` with the filtering mode set to `SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest` the sprite is blurry when scaling.

```
let light = SKLightNode()
light.categoryBitMask = 1
light.falloff = 0.1
light.isEnabled = true
self.addChild(light)

let aSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: aTexture)
aSprite.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest
aSprite.normalTexture = aSprite.texture?.generatingNormalMap()
aSprite.normalTexture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest
aSprite.lightingBitMask = 0b0001
aSprite.setScale(10.0)
self.addChild(aSprite)
```

Here is an example with light source (red dote) and two sprites with the only difference being the `lightingBitMask`

[image]

Is this a bug or is it possible to keep the nearest neighbor filtering mode when scaling yet still use a light source? Or does the normal map get messed up when you scale the sprite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a technical support question about this and they informed me it was a bug.

technical support: 697113125
radar: 44715626

They backtracked on the bug part. This is just a simulator problem. Test on a real device.

> Simulator is **never** a 1-to-1 representation of what you will see on a real device.  It is always best practice to test on a real device!

Comment: It's almost 2020 & they still haven't fixed this bug - currently have the same issue when my camera node zoom is x3 & a light node is present